# Postgres case-insensitive exclusion constraint

Tags: postgresql, database-design, constraints

I'm trying to create an exclusion constraint that prevents overlapping effective timestamp ranges, but only compares ranges across records with the same text value. I'd like the text value comparison to be case insensitive. I can use the `=` operator with a text field, but not with a `citext` field, and the `~~*` operator is not commutative.

This is PostgreSQL 9.5 and the `citext` and `btree_gist` extensions are created on the database.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_product_categories (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
  name text NOT NULL, 
  effective tstzrange DEFAULT '[-infinity,infinity]', 
  EXCLUDE USING gist (name WITH ~~*, effective WITH &&)
)
```

> ```
> ERROR: operator ~~*(text,text) is not commutative
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE customer_product_categories (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
  name citext NOT NULL, 
  effective tstzrange DEFAULT '[-infinity,infinity]', 
  EXCLUDE USING gist (name WITH =, effective WITH &&)
)
```

> ```
> ERROR: operator =(citext,citext) is not a member of operator family "gist_text_ops"
> ```

- How is `ILIKE` not commutative?
- Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do, or am I on a fool's errand?

Comment: A binary operation is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) if changing the order of the operands does not change the result. `ILIKE` is not commutative, e.g. `'a' ~~* '%a'` gives true but `'%a' ~~* 'a'` is false.

Comment: Duh. Wildcards. Thanks @klin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A-ha! I figured it out. I had to go old-school:

```
CREATE TABLE "customer_product_categories" (
  "id" serial PRIMARY KEY, 
  "name" text NOT NULL, 
  "effective" tstzrange DEFAULT '[-infinity,infinity]', 
  EXCLUDE USING gist (LOWER("name") WITH =, "effective" WITH &&)
)
```

Comment: This EXCLUDE statement should work even if you'll keep the `name` column as `citext`.

Comment: @NikitaZhuk Yes, but I didn't need `name` to be `citext`, I was only changing the type to try to make the `EXCLUDE` work.